# Puppeteer Application Error: A client side exception has occurred

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer with NEXT.JS, trying to take a screenshot. And it works fine on localhost but returns an image with this error in production:
**Application error a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information**!!

**Taking a screenshot**

```js
export const createImages = async (urlArray) => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            args: [
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            ],
            slowMo: 250, // slow down by 250ms
        })
        const page = await browser.newPage()

        for (let i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
            if (urlArray[i].address === "") continue
            await page.goto(urlArray[i].address, {
                waitUntil: "load",
                timeout: 30000,
            })

            const screenshotBase64 = await page.screenshot({
                encoding: "base64",
            })
            const screenshot = Buffer.from(
                await screenshotBase64.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),
                "base64"
            )
            urlArray[i]["imgBase64"] = screenshot
        }

        await browser.close()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(new Date(), "was not able to create images: ", err)
        return err
    }

    return 1
}
```

When I open the url manually in production, the page loads fine! And I have tried encoding the image to Binary instead but still the same issue.. Any idea !?

Comment: Puppeteer doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen. I've found this error: 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.' And it point out that the GPU used on the server is blacklisted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I was listening only to the errors. But after I listened to all console messages using this command:

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()))
```

I was able to see this error:
**'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.'**
And it point out that the **GPU** used on the server is blacklisted because it's old.